# How to add a fixed column to the data returned from `select avg` query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any way to add a fixed constant column to the data retrieved from query of Apache IoTDB? The query statement I currently want to use is `select avg(cast(val,'type'='DOUBLE'))as val from root.coal.`CL:BOIL:4#:LOAD `group by([2023-11-01T00:00:00,2023-11-03T00:00:00),1h) fill (0) ALIGN BY DEVICE`, and I also tried to add `as` after this statement, and it does not work. Does anyone know how I should correct this query statement?

Answer (score 0):

Apache IoTDB can create constant time series by using `const` function in the query statement. Try to generate command like `select s1, s2, const(s1, 'value'='1024', 'type'='INT64'), pi(s2), e(s1, s2) from root.sg1.d1`.